# How to get CSS to target new nodes being inserted?

Tags: theming

I am customizing nodes for a blog entree's so they have a certain aesthetic look to it. However, I ran into a problem.

I can enter custom CSS code to style the nodes for already existing ones and set them with classes, but if someone is going to create a new node on the site, the blog CSS doesn't appear because I have to go in to each one and constantly hand-code it.

Obviously this is time-consuming and not the right way to go about it, because anyone who creates a blog would have to wait for me to style it for them. Is there a way where I can make a CSS code that will keep the look and feel every time someone creates a new blog entree?

Comment: Sounds like you're inserting the same CSS into each node manually. That's can't be true right?

Comment: No, that's what I was doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I get the scenario.
What if you apply your css to both old and new classes?

Example

```
.old_nodes .content, .new_nodes .content {
   color:red;
}
```

This will give same style to both new and old nodes.

Comment: I figured it out. I had to install code per node module and use content type styling so each new entry would come with its set prebuilt style.

Comment: From my experience, code per node requires manual action for each node. Happy you figured out, @Shawn !